# Equivalent definitions of markov chains

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I have the following 2 definitions of a Markov chain but I can't see how they are equivalent.

i) Let $X_i$ be a sequence of random variables taking values in a measurable state space $(S,A)$. This process is a discrete Markov chain iff $P(X_{n+1}\in B|\sigma(X_0,X_1,..,X_n))=P(X_{n+1}\in B|\sigma(X_n))$. I'm assuming that $$P(X_{n+1}\in B|\sigma(X_0,X_1,..,X_n))=E[1_{\{X_{n+1}\in B\}}|\sigma(X_0,X_1,..,X_n)]$$

i.e. the conditional expectation of $1_{\{X_{n+1}\in B\}}$ given $\sigma(X_0,X_1,..,X_n)$

ii) The other definition states that $P(X_{n+1}= s|X_0=x_0,X_1=x_1,..,X_n=x_n)=P(X_{n+1}= s|X_n=x_n)$ for all $s,x_0,x_1,x_2,..\in S$. Here, I suppose $$P(X_{n+1}= s|X_0=x_0,X_1=x_1,..,X_n=x_n)=\frac{P(X_{n+1}= s,X_0=x_0,X_1=x_1,..,X_n=x_n)}{P(X_0=x_0,X_1=x_1,..,X_n=x_n)}$$

How are these 2 definitions equivalent?

Edit:

From the following link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property it seems to be the case that they are not equivalent. However, if $S$ is a discrete set with the discrete $\sigma$-algebra then they are equivalent.

In this case the following link provides an explanation: [Why are these two definitions of Markov property equivalent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2962749/why-are-these-two-definitions-of-markov-property-equivalent)

Comment: $\mathsf{E}[Y\mid \sigma(X)]\equiv \mathsf{E}[Y\mid X]$...

Comment: Could you elaborate please

Answer (score 1):

The definitions will be equivalent **IF** all these random variables are discreet (i.e. their ranges are countable). The $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ is then generated by the events $\{X_i=x_i\}$.

If $X_{n+1}$ is not discreet, then $P(X_{n+1}=x_{n+1} \mid \ldots)$ could be identically zero, so it's not clear what the second definition means in that case. The first one, however, is universal.

Conditioning on the event $\{X_1=x_1,\ldots, X_n=x_n\}$ is rather problematic when the random variables involved are continuous.

Comment: By discrete you mean countable?

Comment: Yes. I clarified the answer.

Comment: why do the set $\{X_i=x_i\}$ generate the sigma algebra. The sets $\{X_i=x_i\}$ need not be measurable itself. i.e. $\{x_i\}$ need not be measurable in the sigma algebra of S

Comment: $\sigma(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ is generated by the events $\{X_i \leq x_i\}$, by definition. In the discreet case, $\sigma(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ is also conveniently generated by $\{X_i = x_i\}$.

Comment: I think $\sigma (X_1,..,X_n)$ is generated by $\{X_i\in B\}$ where $B\in A$. How do we know that singleton sets are in A?

Comment: If you are assuming $S=\mathbb{R}$ then yes you would be right. But S is an arbitrary (countable in your case) statespace

Comment: Not sure what $S$ is. I assumed all $X_i$s to be real-valued and defined on a probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$. Secondly, you are correct: $\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ can also be generated by $\{X_i \in B_i\}$, with $B_i$ being a Borel set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in this case I cant assume that S is the set of reals

Comment: You are welcome. However, my answer won't change after replacing $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{R}^k$, $\mathbb{C}$, or similar. Note that $X^{-1}_i(x_i) \in \Sigma$, for every $x_i$, if that's what you mean by singleton sets.